# What i`m doing wrong at my TCP client-server template?

Tags: java, tcp, client-server, bufferedreader

I need to do a simple ADD app using TCP socket, but it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong? 
I've tried already so many ways that I'm thinking I miss something and I do not know what. Can you please help me with some of your knowledge? :)

```
public class Server {

    static int total;
    static int st;
    static int nd;

    public static int sum(int x, int y){
        return x + y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try(ServerSocket appServer = new ServerSocket(631);
                Socket appSocket = appServer.accept();
                BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(appSocket.getInputStream()));
                BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(appSocket.getOutputStream())){

            String line = inStream.readLine();
            while(line!=null&&line.equals("")){
                st = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[0]);
                nd = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[1]);
                total = sum(st,nd);
            }

            String out = String.valueOf(total);
            outStream.write(out.getBytes());
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Server failed.");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}

and those from client:

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String numbers = "1 2";

        try(Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 631);
                BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream())){
                System.out.println("Client connected. Waiting for ADD numbers");
                bos.write(numbers.getBytes());
                bos.flush();

                String res = bis.readLine();
                while((res = bis.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println("The result is " + res);
                }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Connection Problem. " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

Why this doesn't run as expected ( The result is 3 )?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide several fixes:
*`Server`*

```
String line;
while((line = inStream.readLine()) != null ) { // server was blocked here until you send empty line
    if (line.isBlank()) {
        break;
    }
    st = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[0]);
    nd = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[1]);
    total = sum(st,nd);
}

String out = total + "\n";  // << send total with the new-line so that the client could read it
```

*`Client`*  Do not forget to send new line *twice* - 1 to submit numbers and 2 - to let server know that the data transfer completed and it could get out of its reading loop.

```
numbers += "\n\n";
bos.write(numbers.getBytes());
bos.flush();

String res;  // remove reading before the loop to avoid swallowing the server result
while((res = bis.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println("The result is " + res);
}
```

**Update**
Debug logs from the server:

```
2020-05-15T08:31:38.772917900Z: Server started
2020-05-15T08:31:43.280246800Z: Client connected
2020-05-15T08:31:43.313244900Z: Read line from client '1 2'
2020-05-15T08:31:43.313244900Z: Parsing data in the input
2020-05-15T08:31:43.324246400Z: Total calculated: 3
2020-05-15T08:31:43.324246400Z: Read line from client ''
2020-05-15T08:31:43.324246400Z: Reading from client finished, writing response
2020-05-15T08:31:43.329244500Z: Sent response to client
2020-05-15T08:31:43.330245900Z: Server finished, bye
```

Debug logs from client:

```
2020-05-15T08:31:43.240248Z: Client started, numbers = '1 2'
2020-05-15T08:31:43.289246300Z: Sending request to the server, numbers='1 2\n\n'
2020-05-15T08:31:43.291246100Z: Request sent
Waiting for ADD numbers
The result is 3
2020-05-15T08:31:43.334246400Z: Client finished
```

Comment: Alex, I've tried to run with fixes provided and the client process is still stucked (it's not ending + don't show the the result). What can be the problem?

Comment: Hello, please double check that you provided _all_ fixes and learn how to debug the application using your favourite IDE or at least by printing debug messages to the console.  I'm updating my answer with the full debug logs from the client and server as a proof that they work as expected.

Comment: @alender, I just re-copied your code and applied my patches - everything works!
Most likely, you've made some small error when pasting the patches.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, now I`ve learned something new! Its working just fine :-)